# Error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while running swift code with NSURL

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

So, I have built an app that loads data from the iTunes store to display search results with Artist name, song name, and album name. I did this using JSON, and the app works fine on the first run with the search bar I added. I have a `UITextField` in the nav bar, named searchTerm as an `@IBOutlet`, the button is an `@IBAction` function that makes a string from the searchTerm and then fetches the data from the iTunes Store. I load the app fine, it builds successfully, and the first search works. For example, if I search AC/DC, this loads: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSXcG.jpg. If I try to search again, I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Hal.jpg, the app frozen with the previous results, and this error in the console:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

and this error in my `SongsTableViewController` subclass of `UITableViewController`:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Here is my SongsTableViewController class:

```
import UIKit

class SongsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var theSearch = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var searchTerm: UITextField!
    @IBAction func search(sender: AnyObject) {
        theSearch = "\(searchTerm.text)"
        println("searched")
        self.fetchData()
    }
    var songs = [Song]()
    private let cache = NSCache()
    private func fetchData() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(theSearch)&country=us")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            if let taskError = error {
                //handle error
            }
            else {
                let httpResponse = response as NSHTTPURLResponse
                switch httpResponse.statusCode {
                case 200:
                    println("got 200")
                    self.parseJson(data)
                default:
                    println("request failed: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJson(data: NSData) {
        var error: NSError?
        let json : AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)
        if error == nil {
            if let unwrappedJson: AnyObject = json {
                parseSongs(json: unwrappedJson)
            }
        }
    }
    private func parseSongs(#json: AnyObject) {
        songs = []
        if let array = json["results"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
            for songDictionary in array {
                if let title = songDictionary["trackName"] as? NSString {
                    if let artist = songDictionary["artistName"] as? NSString {
                        if let albumName = songDictionary["collectionName"] as? NSString {
                            if let artworkUrl = songDictionary["artworkUrl100"] as? NSString {
                                let song = Song(title: title, artist: artist, albumName: albumName, artworkUrl: artworkUrl)
                                songs.append(song)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return songs.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "\(theSearch) Songs"
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = song.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = song.albumName
        if let image = cache.objectForKey(song.artworkUrl) as? UIImage {
                cell.imageView?.image = image
        }
        else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: song.artworkUrl)!)
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.cache.setObject(image!, forKey: song.artworkUrl)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SongDetailViewController
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)!
        let song = songs[indexPath.row]
        detailViewController.song = song

    }


}
```

and my `SongsDetailViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class SongDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var song: Song?;
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var artistLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.updateView();
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func updateView() {
        println("Code Monkey");
        titleLabel.text = song?.title
        artistLabel.text = song?.artist
    }

}
```

my Song class:

```
import Foundation

struct Song {
    var title: String;
    var artist: String;
    let albumName: String = "";
    let artworkUrl: String = "";
}
```

and the Main.storyboard as xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="6254" systemVersion="14A361p" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="J4e-4J-Qag">
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="6247"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Songs Table View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="o2z-qw-46Z">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="7pZ-HZ-fPi" customClass="SongsTableViewController" customModule="Songs" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="usS-1O-Bb9">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="Cell" textLabel="KyS-jU-iVa" detailTextLabel="v39-NZ-fKp" style="IBUITableViewCellStyleSubtitle" id="Dxe-az-DTs">
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="Dxe-az-DTs" id="s0z-IA-UE6">
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                    <subviews>
                                        <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Title" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="KyS-jU-iVa">
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="16"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                        <label opaque="NO" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="left" text="Subtitle" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" id="v39-NZ-fKp">
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="11"/>
                                            <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                        </label>
                                    </subviews>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                <connections>
                                    <segue destination="IaK-66-iRk" kind="show" identifier="showSongDetails" id="Qvk-MK-NHw"/>
                                </connections>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="7pZ-HZ-fPi" id="1Fa-g3-eTG"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="7pZ-HZ-fPi" id="F2P-n2-c00"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="DSQ-mu-WTl">
                        <nil key="title"/>
                        <textField key="titleView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" minimumFontSize="17" id="OyO-T3-pkK" userLabel="Search">
                            <rect key="frame" x="180" y="7" width="240" height="30"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                            <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                        </textField>
                        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" style="plain" id="fPc-Nn-AF7">
                            <button key="customView" opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="hzA-Ku-WOK">
                                <rect key="frame" x="-23" y="-15" width="133" height="30"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Go">
                                    <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                </state>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="search:" destination="7pZ-HZ-fPi" eventType="touchUpInside" id="9ny-cc-B47"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <connections>
                                <action selector="search" destination="7pZ-HZ-fPi" id="Mav-7f-Nw9"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="searchTerm" destination="OyO-T3-pkK" id="LGU-GM-rOh"/>
                    </connections>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="pBf-2K-Quz" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1091" y="421"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Song Detail View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EY0-P9-lxp">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="IaK-66-iRk" customClass="SongDetailViewController" customModule="Songs" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="NcC-3p-PzZ"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="v8u-7K-8VY"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Gag-Xd-hMv">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" ambiguous="YES" misplaced="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="neB-pw-mZC">
                                <rect key="frame" x="115" y="216" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" ambiguous="YES" misplaced="YES" text="Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="aXT-AM-FSZ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="115" y="289" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="neB-pw-mZC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="NcC-3p-PzZ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="154" id="PwZ-wP-g5X"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="aXT-AM-FSZ" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="neB-pw-mZC" secondAttribute="centerX" constant="3" id="SJa-en-Fsl"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="aXT-AM-FSZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="neB-pw-mZC" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="50" id="qCi-A1-mRH"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="artistLabel" destination="aXT-AM-FSZ" id="3tP-9I-8KR"/>
                        <outlet property="titleLabel" destination="neB-pw-mZC" id="kBk-Wt-IOE"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="nNS-Sx-Qsb" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1943" y="411"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="d4l-Tj-sHo">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="J4e-4J-Qag" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="JSx-T8-Kzc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="7pZ-HZ-fPi" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="iec-gq-WSz"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ho4-Dh-fvD" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="279" y="421"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

I know that unwrapping nil is bad, but why does it unwrap nil? The nil occurs on the `SongsTableViewController` line with `let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {`, where `url` is what has been unwrapped and is nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your app crashes when you search for songs with a space in the name is because that results in an invalid url. To build an URL you need to do proper escaping. If you don't then `NSURL(string: ...)` will return nil.

You don't actually check if `url` is valid (not nil), so your app crashes as soon as you try to use it.

Ideally what you should really do is use `NSURLComponents` to construct the URL. It will take a base URL, path and query arguments and mangle everything together as a valid `NSURL` instance, doing all the proper encoding and escaping.

If you create a function that encapsulates that logic then you can do something as follows:

```
private func fetchData() {
    if let url = searchURLWithTerm("Foo Fighters") {
        ... rest of your code here ...
    }
}

func searchURLWithTerm(term: String) -> NSURL? {
    if let components = NSURLComponents(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/search") {
        components.queryItems = [NSURLQueryItem(name: "country", value: "US"),
            NSURLQueryItem(name: "term", value: term)]
        return components.URL
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I am curious why I am down voted. The answer that is marked as correct is actually incorrect and incomplete.

Comment: @DownVoter This answer is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
url!
```

instead use

```
if let url = url {
}
```

To make sure that it is not nil.

Now, the reason it not working is probably less with the nils, and more with the actual data in the string for NSURL. Log it every time it changes, and try to use it in postman. If it works - you are sending the request wrong. If it fails in postman, its a bad url.

Look into NSURLConnection, send asynchronous request, it makes error catching much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just realized that it was **just** search terms with a space in them that got the error! So, if I include %20 in the search, it loads! I will fix this, and I would not have if you had not pointed out the bad url!

Comment: Great :) 

Accept my answer if it help! Happy Friday!

Comment: This is the wrong advice. It should be `if let url = url {`

Comment: I will accept in 6 minutes! I would give you points, but I do not have enough! (hint)

Comment: Also, instead of including %20 in the search, check this out 


`NSString *formattedUrl =[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`